# Lightning Experience Detail Page Inline Editing Rendering bug

Tags: lightning-experience

Has anyone faced this situation ?

It's working as expected in firefox & chrome, but with IE(11 if that matters) :

As a user, in lightning experience, go on a detail page, double click on a field value to change it. Asap a popup shows [image].

The user can dismiss the popup and applies modification. But once he's done, the browser is locked from any event (due to javascript malfunction probably).

I know that Internet Explorer is no longer fully supported for Lightning Experience. And officially done with it on December 2017, but until then can we do something ?